# How to return the timestamps from an indexed array of timestamps with the earliest and latest clock time?

Tags: php, arrays, time, max, min

There is a large array with timestamps, e.g.:

```
$timestamps = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    $timestamps[] = mt_rand(strtotime('1900-01-01 00:00:00 am'), strtotime('2100-12-31 11:59:59 pm'));
}
```

Now I need to return the timestamps with the earliest (min) and latest (max) clock time.

My approach:

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', min(array_map('callback', $timestamps)));
echo "\n";
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', max(array_map('callback', $timestamps)));

function callback($timestamp) {
    return strtotime(date('h:i:s a', $timestamp));
}
```

This actually provides the earliest and latest clock time, but of course along with the current date (today).

How to return the original timestamps with the earliest and latest clock time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next code:

```
//run array_reduce over array
$res = array_reduce(
    $timestamps, // timestaps array
    function($res, $t) {
        // get time from timestamp
        $time = date('H:i:s', $t);

        // if result min not exists
        // or more then $time store new value to $res['min']
        if (is_null($res['min'][0]) || $time<$res['min'][0])
            $res['min'] = [$time, date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', $t)];


        // if result max not exists
        // or less then $time store new value to $res['max']
        if (is_null($res['max'][0]) || $time>$res['max'][0])
            $res['max'] = [$time, date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', $t)];

        // return updated result
        return $res;
    },
    // define initial $res with null values
    ['min'=>[null, null], 'max'=>[null, null]]
);
```

[Share PHP online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=f45f96b899ec3e570f07a7478c905043&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Result:

```
Array
(
    [min] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00:00:30
            [1] => 1997-05-03 12:00:30 am
        )

    [max] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23:59:36
            [1] => 1983-07-21 11:59:36 pm
        )

)
```

Comment: Could you explain your code in detail? Is it possible with `array_map()`, too?

Comment: Sure, added comments

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible with `array_map()`, too?

Comment: May be. Not sure. array_map function used to change each element of given array, but array_reduce - reduce array to needle value

Comment: Using array_map: https://phpize.online/?phpses=91a38e101385027e0831deda10145675&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: I suggest you to add the `array_map()` solution directly to your answer as an alternative. And something else crossed my mind: What if there are two or more timestamps with the exact same clock time? How could I return **all** `min` and `max` matches?